# Some letters of Google Fonts appear broken on Mac

Tags: macos, web, fonts, font-face

Some letters of Google Fonts (Work Sans, Exo 2 tested) appear broken on Mac when used on a website and viewed in a browser (or printed).

Why is it that way and is there a solution?

Example of an "A" of Work Sans in a website viewed in a browser on Mac.

[image: "A" on Mac in Work Sans]

Reference:
[Work sans on Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Work+Sans)

Comment: I can report the same. This is very strange, we did several tests (local download, remote hosting, font conversion); There doesn't seem to be a pattern, which is working everywhere.

Comment: We are using Chrome on Mac with the Google Fonts Work Sans in .woff (not .woff2) extension and the "A" letter appears as you reported it.

Comment: I tried every file format Google offered (woff, woff2, ttf, svg, eot) and it didn't work. According to my sources who are testing it on Mac it works on http://series.hashtagsunplugged.com/breaktheinternet though. Are the letters displayed correctly for you there when you view it on Mac?

Comment: @ctekk, in this website series.hashtagsunplugged.com/breaktheinternet, the fonts are loaded from the same domain. The idea is to use the Google Fonts domain. So maybe they downloaded the fonts when they were working properly.

Comment: I just saw that the font author provided an update which fixed it: https://github.com/weiweihuanghuang/Work-Sans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font author recently provided an update which fixed it (for work sans):

https://github.com/weiweihuanghuang/Work-Sans

Comment: I'm currently using `<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans [...]>` to load the font. How can I load the fix using the Google Fonts CDN? (or another CDN)?